# Libclang Python Binding: Get ObjC Method Return Value

Tags: python, objective-c, swift, clang, libclang

### Background

Please see https://github.com/tingraldi/SwiftScripting/issues/18 for a full discussion of this problem.

The link above has a long Python script that translates an Objective-C `File.h` header file into `File.swift`. To do this, it uses libclang to parse the file and translate the AST into Swift output.

Here is the abbreviated content of the header file we're processing:

```
@interface FinderContainer : FinderItem

- (SBElementArray<FinderItem *> *) items;
- (SBElementArray<FinderContainer *> *) containers;

@end
```

---

### The Issue

On macOS 10.13.6 with Xcode 9.4.1 and `pip install clang==3.5`, the script runs perfectly and generates the correct output:

```
@objc public protocol FinderContainer: FinderItem {
    @objc optional func items() -> SBElementArray
    ...  // Truncated
}
```

HOWEVER, on macOS Mojave with Xcode 10 installed and the same `pip install clang==3.5`, the return values of the functions are missing:

```
@objc public protocol FinderContainer: FinderItem {
    @objc optional func items()
    ...  // Truncated
}
```

Note: I have tested clang 3.5 and the latest version: 6.0.0.2. Both yield the same result.

---

### What's Going Wrong

This part of the python script consumes a function/method declaration and translates it to Swift:

```
def emit_function(self, cursor):
    
    # ----LOGGING ADDITIONS -------------------------------------------------
    print(cursor.spelling)
    parameter_children_names = [child for child in cursor.get_children()]
    for x in parameter_children_names: print('   child --> ' + x.spelling)
    print('   result_type: ' + str(cursor.result_type.kind))
    # -----------------------------------------------------------------------

    func_name = safe_name(cursor.spelling.split(':')[0], keywords=general_keywords)
    parameter_cursors = [child for child in cursor.get_children() if child.kind == CursorKind.PARM_DECL]
    parameters = ['{}: {}'.format(arg_name(child.spelling, position=parameter_cursors.index(child)), type_for_type(child.type, as_arg=True))
                  for child in parameter_cursors]
    return_type = [child.type for child in cursor.get_children() if child.kind != CursorKind.PARM_DECL]
    if return_type:
        return_string = ' -> {}'.format(type_for_type(return_type[0]))
    else:
        return_string = ''

    self.emit_line('    @objc optional func {}({}){}{}'.format(
        func_name, ", ".join(parameters), return_string, self.line_comment(cursor)))
```

On macOS 10.13, the logged output looks like this:

[image]

The name of each Clang `cursor` appears on the left and indented below are each of the cursor's children. You can see that ONE of those children is the return value `SBElementArray`. You can also see that the `return_type.kind` value is not defined. The script walks through the children of `cursor` until it finds one that is not of the `parameter` type. It knows this child is the return value, pulls it out, and writes the correct Swift code.

On macOS Mojave, the return value is no longer a child of `cursor` as shown in the logging output:

[image]

So, in this case, the script finds no return value and the function is now written incorrectly.

---

### My Question

How do I fix this? I have spent hours reading Clang documentation, looking for change logs, etc. I cannot figure out (A) what changed and (B) what the new approach to get the return value of the function/method should be.

I need someone who knows Clang better than I do. Thank you.